# I cannot use -r option in bash read command. Why?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I try to write a very basic command line with colours in linux terminal:

```
user@DESKTOP:~$ r="\e[0;31m"

user@DESKTOP:~$ read -r -p "${r}Type number: " number
\e[0;31mType number: 15
```

No colours...

And if I try this:

```
user@DESKTOP:~$ read -p -r "${r}Type number: " number
-bash: read: `\e[0;31mType number: ': not a valid identifier
```

I got this error. I do some search and I saw that there are people using -r option to enable backslash to use escape characters. But why isn't it working for me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-r` is used to avoid parsing backslashes *in the input* as part of escape sequences, it won't help you have your prompt colored.

You can use [`$'ANSI-C quoting'`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) to reproduce the behaviour of `echo`'s `-e` flag :

```
red=$'\e[0;31m'
reset=$'\e[0m'
read -p "${red}Type number: ${reset}" number
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand that why we use $ in variables? Normally without $ symbol, it's fine. Because of read command? If so why?

Comment: @AhmetMehmet that's because you want `\e` (and what follows) to be parsed as an escape sequence. Normally those are ignored by your shell, i.e. they're just considered as a backslash character followed by other characters. You can tell `echo` to parse them as the escape sequences they are by using its `-e` flag, or you can tell `bash` itself to parse them as escape sequences by using `$'...'` ANSI-C quoting

Comment: Thanks! Now I totally understand it.

Comment: You're welcome ! Sorry your question was closed with such a bullshit reason by the way, but consider posting further questions on shell commands use on the [Unix&Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) rather than on StackOverflow, they'll be more relevant and better received there.

Answer (score 0):

With read try this

> read -p $'\e[31mType number \e[0m: ' number

the **\e[31m** set Red color **\e[0m** to return back to the simple bash color.